# xdcr replication of identical data

Tags: couchbase

i will be using couchbase as the database for my website. i plan for the website to be international so i will probably have datacenters in the usa, europe and australia to keep latency low. i also want to minimise bandwidth between datacenters so i am planning to fire off parallel updates (ajax) to all datacenters whenever the user stores data.

my question is then: if i insert the same data into all three clusters approximately simultaneously, is couchbase smart enough to recognize that this data is identical and therefore does not need replicating between datacenters?

i watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=za6CW9UJoWk) and he explained that the cas value is updated when a document is updated and this is used to determine which documents require replication. if the cas value is updated when any document on the cluster is updated then my guess is that the answer is "no" - as it is very likely that i may be sending only some data to all 3 clusters at once, and any data which is sent to only one cluster will get the cas temporarily out of sync for that cluster. however if the cas value is independent per document then the answer may be "yes". maybe there are some options which can be altered to make the cas value independent per document?

Comment: All recent versions of a document would be sent via the unidirectional replication that you would need to set up. The documents would need to be sent so that the most recent is available in each cluster. Additionally, and depending on the performance of remote sites, you could end up causing the browser to queue Ajax requests as it waits for its non-primary data centers to respond.

Comment: but does couchbase just do some kind of comparison between clusters (eg comparing the cas values) then not bother with sending the bulky document content when it sees that they are the same?

Comment: Minimally, it would send: Numerical sequence, which is incremented on each mutation; CAS value; Document flags; Expiration (TTL) value. If the document is determined to be unique or newer, the document is replicated.

Comment: thanks for the info. do you know if any of these comparison parameters can be turned off (for example can the timestamp comparison be disabled)?

Comment: It's not documented that you can disable them.

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase does not know anything about the body of the documents that you store.  From it's perspective, if you write the same document to 3 clusters (all linked bi-directionally with XDCR) it considers them 3 different document mutations to the document with that ID.  Couchbase will perform its normal conflict resolution process to choose which of the 3 is the "winner".  This will result in "winning" document being transferred to the other two clusters, despite the fact that it may have the exact same content as the "losing" revisions.

Anytime you write to the same document ID in different clusters, you have to be aware that conflict resolution will choose the winning revision.  If you're not careful you can overwrite data you didn't mean to.

Typically a different approach is chosen for your use case.  For each user, a "home" cluster is chosen, probably based geography.  All operations are tied to this cluster for that user.  If that cluster is down, you can switch to another cluster.  Using this approach you avoid writing to multiple clusters, and you would only change clusters under well defined conditions.

The CAS value is just an opaque identifier of the revision.  In your example above, all 3 document writes would end up with different CAS values (which is one of the reasons Couchbase sees them as different, and has to choose a winner)

The conflict resolution process is document in [this section of the manual](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-admin-tasks-xdcr-functionality.html)